# Where is Spring Boot's ResourceNotFoundException?

Tags: spring-boot

We used to have `org.springframework.boot.context.config.ResourceNotFoundException` in Spring Boot 1.5.4. Where is this in Spring Boot 2.0 `(2.0.4.RELEASE)`?

Comment: Removed my answer; I tried using a new version of Spring Boot and couldn't find it either.  Looks like @Todd found the reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like that class was deleted for Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1, according to [this diff](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/b98c7ed9f870ae7321cdbb6ea880052a6fca8a68). Judging from that diff, they expect you to use different exceptions for this namely InvalidConfigurationPropertyValueException. I suspect this change was made to use more explicit exceptions to trigger more accurate Failure Analyzers.